# OpenCV dll-call tracer

Tags: opencv, dll, reverse-engineering

Once I was in need to understand a not documented USB-device (the supplier went bankrupt) I've written a wrapper for FTDI-dll which has traced all the calls with all the data passing in and out.

Now I wonder is there anything similar for OpenCV? Are there wrapper dlls for OpenCV which log all API-calls?

Of course, one could modify code and log all the calls, but is there an option built in OpenCV already?

Thank you for any hint!